# Using GRASS v.delaunay with QGIS results with gaps in triangulation

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, geometry, error, delaunay

When I use the GRASS `v.delaunay` algortithm in  QGIS 3.18 on my dataset the output has gaps in it. But when I use the QGIS delaunay algorithm there are no problems and all is triangulated.

[image: v.delaunay output]

[image: qgis delaunay output]

The input that I use is a pointlayer with xyz geometry and the algorithms are called on from the processing toolbox. The settings for `v.delaunay` are shown below.

[image: v.delaunay settings]

And these are the warnings.

[image: v.delaunay warnings]

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: How do you use the algorithm? What datasets are you using? What type are they? Post some screen dumps. It will be easier to help if we can see.

Comment: I've added some more information

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data to reproduce the error? I tried the tool with a point layer in `EPSG:28992` and did not get any errors.

Comment: Hi, a gpkg with all the points can be found at [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArUeDCs3uIG1gs5p6vBVmslvqQjzkQ?e=HjqJv8)

Comment: The vector map is topologically incorrect... WARNING: Number of incorrect boundaries: 170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems with the gaps within the triangulation with `v.delaunay` is solved with the solution as provided by @Babel. But along the borders there were points in this dataset that were left out of the triangulation and lines (brown) ended up not as expected (blue).[image: output_vs_expected]

The following steps helped me to get the output I want.

1. `remove duplicate geometries` and add a field with the z value. Formula = `z ($geometry)`
2. create new field in step 1 with @Babels's formula

`if ( length ( make_line( $geometry,  array_first ( overlay_nearest( @layer,  $geometry ) ) ) ) > 0.001, 'true', if ( array_first ( overlay_nearest ( @layer, $id ) )< $id, 'true', 'false' ) )`

3. `select by expression` with expression `"fieldname" = 'True'`
4. `v.delaunay` with step 3 as input and use `selected features only`

This gives me a triangulation that filled the gaps on the inside, but with unexpected sides. [image: output step 4]

To fix these:

5. `minimum bounding geometry` with step 1 as input. Type geometry = convex hull
6. `buffer` step 5, in this case I used a 1 meter buffer
7. `extract vertices` of step 6
8. `join by nearest` step 7 as first input and step 1 as second
9. `set z-value` step 8, get z value from the field made in step 1
10. `merge vector layers` from step 1 and step 9
11. repeat step 2,3 and 4
12. `merge vectorlayers` step 4 and 11
13. `remove duplicate geometries` of step 12
14. `extract by location` input is step 13 extract objects `within` step 5.
    This gives the output I expected.

[image: output step 14]

Comment: OK, nice to see. But why don't you use the QGIS native delaunay algorith? It would be much simpler to use and gives the result you're looking for?

Comment: Well, GRASS delaunay has a xyz output, so all the nodes have the same z-value as the input points. QGIS delaunay has a xy output, so in order to get the z-value I must interpolate the input points and use drape to add the z-value to the nodes. And this step increases the chance of deviations. I can use these triangulated surfaces with my survey equipment.

Answer (score 3):

**What the problem was: duplicate points**

After inspecting your data, I could identify the problem: you have a lot of duplicate points as well as a few points that are "almost" duplicates (extremely close to each other). From originally 954 features in the point layer you provided, only 229 (ca. 24%) are really unique points (thus not duplicates or quasi-duplicates).

You can see this: set your layer rendering style to `Point Cluster` (see screenshots 2 and 3 below), than you see how many points are in the same place or extremely close together.

This causes the problem with `v.delaunay` (and, by the way, similarily with `v.voronoi` as well). Polygons would get extremely small. It seems that the native QGIS algorithm for Delaunay Triangulation (and Voronoi polygons as well) tolerates this, whereas the GRASS tool does not.

**How to solve the problem: remove duplicates and very close points**

1. Remove duplicate points: `Menu Processing / Tollbox / Delete duplicate geometries`. This reduces your point layer from originally 954 features down to 243 features.
2. Remove the points that are "almost" duplicates (extremely close). I created a new attribute field with field calculator to measure the distance from each point to it's next neighbor. It keeps points that have a certain minimum distance from the next neighbor. For points extremely close to it's next neighbor, it keeps only the one with the lower `$id` value. This is the expression that returns `true` for points to keep and `false` for all points to ignore - minimum distance to keep points set to `0.001` (this marks another 14 features to be ignored):

```
if (
    length (
        make_line(
            $geometry, 
            array_first (
                overlay_nearest( 
                    @layer, 
                    $geometry
                )
            )
        )
    ) > 0.001,
    'true',
    if (
        array_first (
            overlay_nearest (
                @layer,
                $id
            )
        )< $id,
        'true',
        'false'
    )
)
```

3. Use `select by expression` to select those features with attribute-value of the field created in step 2  `= 'true'`. Calculation will be done for only 229 features out of 954 as you originally have.
4. Now run `v.delaunay` and check the box next to `Selected features only`

*Screenshot 1: `v.delaunay` with default settings and checked box `Selected features only` (red frame) results in the orange output. Overlayed, semi-transparent polygons created with the same tool, based on the original points you provided for comarison: the "holes" are now filled, the same way as with native QGIS Delaunay algorithm:*

[image]

*Screenshot 2: Your original point layer, containing 954 features, many of them duplicates as you can see when rendering with `Point Cluster`:*

[image]

*Screenshot 3: after removing duplicates (step 1), you're left with 243 features, some of them de-facto duplicates as the next screenshot shows. They appear exactly where your problems are:*

[image]

*Screenshot 4: There are still areas left where you have extremely small, obtuse angled triangles. Reason is that you have points that are almost, but not exactly on a line - see on the next image (rotated, to be better visible). In QGIS native output, the area is calculated as 0, in `v.delaunay` output, it gives a value > 0. So it least in my understanding, `v.delaunay` is more correct:*
[image]

Comment: The surrounding holes are calculated this way, but it still gives the  incorrect boundaries warning. Along the north and south borders there are still points that aren't triangulated, but are triangulated with the QGIS delaunay algorithm.

Comment: How many input features do you have? When I reduced to points to 243 features, no holes were produced with `v.delaunay`. So please check if you have more points left.

Comment: When I follow your steps I also have 243 points left and 229 selected for the input. When I run `v.delaunay` with this input it gives a warning that there are 109 incorrect boundaries.

Comment: Don't select - use all 243 for the input, than no error should be returned - right?

Comment: When I don't select, it gives the area of size = 0.0 ignored warning and 172 incorect boundaries. The outcomes are as shown in your first screenshot.

Comment: OK, so output is OK, but you are concerned because of the warning? I also get a warning about incorrect boundaries, but still the output seems to be valid. If  the original problem of the gaps is solved, I suppose you post the question about the error messages as a separate question to draw more attention to it and because it is a different problem from the one asked first. By the way: if I create an attribute for the area of the output, all features have an area > 0 - isn't that the case with your output?

Comment: Inspecting the results with GRASS v.delaunay and QGIS native Delaunay, both contain some extremely small, obtuse angled triangles. Reason is that you have points that are almost, but not exactly on a line. In QGIS native output, the area is calculated as `0`, in v.delaunay output, it gived a value > 0. So it least in my understanding, v.delaunay is more correct.

Comment: See updated answer with screenshot of one of these extremely small sliver polygons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124337/discussion-between-lars81-and-babel).

Comment: Just another idea: try rounding the postion (x/y coordinate values) of your (remaining) points an re-position them there to avoid cases like you have, e.g. three points that probably should be on a straight line, but in fact are being positioned in the form of an extremely tiny triangle (sliver polygon).